# Вернуть класс, свойством которого является другой класс

Tags: c#

Как сделать так, чтобы возвращались все свойства класса(включая свойства класса `Model2`)?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{    
    public class Model1
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
        public string Property3 { get; set; }
        public string Property4 { get; set; }
        public Model2 Model2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Model2
    {
        public string Property5 { get; set; }
        public string Property6 { get; set; }
        public string Property7 { get; set; }
        public string Property8 { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static Model1 Main(string[] args)
        {
            return new Model1
            {
                Property1 = "1",
                Property2 = "2",
                Property3 = "3",
                Property4 = "4",
                new Model2
                { 
                    Property5 = "5", 
                    Property6 = "6", 
                    Property7 = "7",
                    Property8 = "8"
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: возвращались куда?

Comment: Возвращались в методе, для дальнейшего вызов и обработки в другом методе. Например 
var M = Main();
(Грубый пример)

Comment: Что именно ты хочешь получить в итоге? Список значений методов? Список имен методов? Все вместе?

Comment: Так должны и сейчас вернуться, что не так?

Comment: Должно, но не возвращается. Хочу обращаться к свойствам метода Model1 и Model2, например Model1.Model2.Property5. Ошибка выдается уже при присваивании

Answer (score -1):

```
class Program
{
    public static Model1 Main(string[] args)
    {
        return new Model1
        {
            Property1 = "1",
            Property2 = "2",
            Property3 = "3",
            Property4 = "4",
            Model2 = new Model2
            {
                Property5 = "5",
                Property6 = "6",
                Property7 = "7",
                Property8 = "8"
            }
        };
    }
}

var main = Program.Main(null);
string p5 = main.Model2.Property5;
WriteLine(p5); //вывод: 5
```

Хотя не представляю зачем это вам и в таком виде.

Comment: И что? Собралось такое приложение?

Comment: @こきん ага, в интеррактиве.

Comment: @こきん [тыц](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/top-level-statements).